# how to copy all attributed content from NSTextView to NSPasteboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nspasteboard

I'm trying to implement auto copy content from NSTextView to clipboard for pasting it in editor in the future. NSTextView has plain and attributed text and images.

If I select all and copy by pressing CMD+C and paste to some rich editor (for example Mail.app) everything is fine.

I found this solution to copy RTF on [CocoaDev.com](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CopyRTFFromTextView5)

But when I'm trying to copy my content through this solution is nothing happening if I pasting then in editor.

How to copy attributed text with images from NSTextView textStorage to NSPasteboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that was needed is to use NSRTFDPboardType.

Answer (score 0):

Your text view's text storage is an instance of NSTextStorage, which is a subclass of NSMutableAttributedString. With that in mind, look at [Copy NSAttributedString to pasteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581407/copy-nsattributedstring-to-pasteboard) and you'll have everything you need to move forward.