# about UIPasteboard clip

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipasteboard

I want to implement a clipboard app using UIPasteboard, which can copy plain text and also rich format , web content in to the pasteboard , and then display on my TextView or WebView. how can i do that?

i have following code and it can get the plain text , but what if i copy a web content?

```
if ([pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.utf8-plain-text", @"public.text", nil]]){
    if (![_contentList containsObject:pasteboard.string]){
        NSLog(@"String representation present: %@", pasteboard.string);
        [self addContentList:pasteboard.string];
        [pasteboard setValue:@"" forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIPasteboardTypeListString` instead

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]; 
if (pasteboard.string != nil) {
    [self insertText:pasteboard.string]; 
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Comment: i think this can only catch a string , what if i copy a web content ? such as html ?

Comment: See the answer here for rich text - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12603189/46297 Not sure if it will work when copying from a web page though.

Comment: This not the cases, what i want is get the content from UIPasteboard, but not set content in it.