# How can I copy text to clipboard with format info in ios?

Tags: ios, fonts, copy, clipboard

I am building a new app. I want to share some texts to another app. eg, iMessage, Notes and so on.

The problem is I can show these texts as "Courier"(monospaced font). But how can I tell iMessage or Notes show these texts as the same font?

UIPasteboard can do it?

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601039/copy-nsattributedstring-in-uipasteboard) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Q: UIPasteboard can do it?

Ans: No.

the fonts are set by each UIControl that belong to each apps.
One idea to do this is to capture the font as image, and copy that image
into UIPasteboard. But not sure if that's acceptable by you.

Cheers