# paste of nsmutableattributed string to public pasteboard loses attributes in pages

Tags: objective-c, nspasteboard, iwork

I am creating a mac standalone service that puts attributed strings on a pasteboard. When the data is accessed by pages, the string loses its attributes. I am using the following code to paste the string, with the NSReturnTypes value set to NSStringPboardType.

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Yay, I'm a string"];

[str beginEditing];

[str addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
               value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineByWord]
               range:NSMakeRange(0,str.length)];

[str endEditing];

[pboard clearContents];
[pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:str]];
```

Non iWork applications such as notes and mail can process the attributes just fine but pages insists on dropping them. How can I create pasteboard data that is processable by pages, keynote, and numbers?

*UPDATE:* Apparantly iWork applies the current style up to the first newline on text that is pasted over already existing text in the document. I am assuming that paragraph styles are behind this, but would appreciate any help here.

*UPDATE2:* It appears to be a bug in how pages accepts data from the clipboard.

Comment: Similar but old question: [Copy NSAttributedString to pasteboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581407/copy-nsattributedstring-to-pasteboard/2585327#2585327)

Comment: Copy in Pages and paste in Pages also changes the style. Looks like a bug in Pages to me.

Comment: It is indeed a bug in pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Pages, or intended behavior. https://discussions.apple.com/message/30971829?ac_cid=op123456#30971829

Comment: But can you work around/with it? There is no indication in that thread you've looked at the clipboard - Apple have a sample to help you, see addendum to my answer. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has offered you anything yet, so here is an approach not an answer as such:

> I am assuming that paragraph styles are behind this, but would appreciate any help here.

Don't assume, test.

Write a simple app which allows you to examine what is on the clipboard. Then open TextEdit & Pages and copy & paste things both in and between the apps. See what is on the clipboard. Pages does a certain amount of "match style" pasting even when "Paste and Match Style" is *not* selected.

Note of course that this issue is not restricted to your app, as you'll see when copying from TextEdit (or Word *et al*) into Pages. Your aim appears to be to replicate Pages to Pages copy & paste, it may or may not be possible.

**Addendum**

If you need help with viewing the clipboard Apple have sample code to do it, [ClipboardViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008825-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). Just compare your underlined word when copied from TextEdit and Pages. Quite a few differences including iWork specific data types.

HTH